# Using jQuery to handle JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this little problem with json.

```
//real json
var json1 = {"test1":"TEST1","test2":"TEST2","test3":"TEST3","test4":"TEST4"};
alert(json.test1); // will echo TEST1
//string, so javascript treat it like a String not JSON
var json2 = "{"test1":"TEST1","test2":"TEST2","test3":"TEST3","test4":"TEST4"}";
alert(json2.test1); // wrong
```

Now I think you know what I mean, Is there any function or a way to convert that json-like string into a actual JSON?

Comment: **Small typo in your first alert of code** `var json1 = {"test1":"TEST1","test2":"TEST2","test3":"TEST3","test4":"TEST4"}; //change as json1 alert(json1.test1); // will echo TEST1`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: because I thought in jQuery there must be a way to solve this issue, and jQuery.parseJSON is the way!

Comment: @DidierGhys I know that even you should be very careful in coding...sometimes this also give you an error........Check out the other way of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your string is actually valid, eg (note the single quotes)

```
var json2 = '{"test1":"TEST1","test2":"TEST2","test3":"TEST3","test4":"TEST4"}';
```

Use

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json2);
alert(jsonObj.test1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way to do this with jQuery:

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Of course, you don't need jQuery for this, and you could accomplish the same thing with this:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

The theory is [explained here](http://www.json.org/js.html), and you can also check out the [jQuery.parseJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval() function:

```
var real_json = eval(json2);
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it says Syntax Error Unexpected token :

Comment: Try `eval('(' + json2 + ')')`. And make sure your `json2` string is escaped properly in your code (it's not in your example).

Comment: eval opens a big security hole, because it will process any javascript code. If the string you pass it isn't json, it might cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this also an another way of JSON Parsing**

```
var json2 = "{"+'"test1"'+":"+'"TEST1"'+","+'"test2"'+":"+'"TEST2"'+","+'"test3"'+":"+'"TEST3"'+","+'"test4"'+":"+'"TEST4"'+"}";

      var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(json2);
      alert(jsonObj.test1);
```